# Resolving private ip using device name/hostname

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, dhcp, dhcp-server

I am programming for a raspberry pi headless setup and I and my cross-compiling toolchain ssh into it very frequently. The device name it registers with to my wifi router is "rpi" and something like "rpi.local" or just "rpi" resolves to a valid ipv6 (as opposed to the ipv4 given to it by the DHCP server in my router) and works as expected. For example:

1. `ssh username@rpi` works.
2. If I deploy a server on rpi's localhost, typing something like `rpi.local/` lands me the root index of my webserver.

The problem is it works sporadically. Most of the time it just doesn't work.

My question is, why does it happen and why isn't it persistent or if there are any ways to make it work without modifying the hosts file on my windows laptop?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the symptoms when it doesn't work? Have you noticed some pattern for its (not) working?

Comment: @harrymc none at all. It just randomly works after a reboot on the raspberry pi. But after most reboots, it mostly doesn't work but sometimes it does. Only pattern is that if it works, it works till the next reboot.

Answer (score 1):

`.local` implies multicast DNS. You mentioned Wi-Fi. Handling multicasts on Wi-Fi is tricky, and lots of APs (wireless routers) and Wi-Fi client devices are buggy in their multicast handling, causing multicast to stop working while everything else is still working fine.

Next time the problem happens, see if it's multicast in general that has broken, by pinging the all-hosts multicast addresses (224.0.0.1 and ff02::1) and see if you get ping responses from all the other devices (do this from each device involved, because it's common for multicasts to only break in one direction). Better yet, try this out when the problem is NOT happening first, so you are familiar with how it SHOULD work. If your RPi's name doesn't resolve and multicast pings don't work, you have a multicast problem that's breaking multicast name service, not a name resolution problem *per se*. So that will tell you if you need to start troubleshooting this as a Wi-Fi multicast breakage problem.

Historically one of the most common things buggy Wi-Fi equipment mishandles with multicast is dealing with multiple security ciphers on the network, such as WPA+WPA2 mixed mode (a.k.a. TKIP + AES-CCMP). Make sure your AP does not have original WPA (TKIP) enabled in any way, not even as an option. Go with pure WPA2-PSK only (AES-CCMP only).

Comment: Thank you for this clear and excellent answer. I had no idea about this multicast thing. And yes, it stops working together with the ipv6. That doesn't resolve either.